# Rolled back Windows 11 Insider VM to Windows 10 and my product key does not work

Tags: windows-10, vmware-player, windows-11

I reinstalled an evaluation version of Enterprise to replace my insider 11, since I don't have a TPM installed.  It (Windows 11) got installed up to a certain point but then stopped letting me update.

This evaluation version in my VM is not pre-activated, leaving me to believe the reinstall changed whatever Microsoft used to check for a digital license.

I tried entering the same product key into my VM to activate it, and they told me the product key did not work.

How can I release the key so I can again consume it from this VM?

Comment: Are you sure the temporary license just hasn’t expired? Why don’t you just simply recreate the VM? You don’t have a permanent license so there isn’t a key to “release” of course that isn’t really a thing anyway (since Enterprise is completely managed by a KMS)

Comment: I have a valid key that was used in the VM.  The key does not work anymore after I reformatted the VM.

Comment: FWIW, 72 days left in the Enterprise trial.